# Blown varistor after connecting UPS?

Tags: ups, surge-protection, varistor

I have a pellet burning stove and the manufacturer provides for two options for battery backups. One is an inverter and deep cycle battery that can run the device for a few hours, the other is a UPS that will basically run it until it the fire stops.

I couldn't find the specified UPS, and the replacement version had a bit more oomph so I thought I was safe. I checked the wattage/amperage against the old version and it looked ok. Stove uses 150W at full load and up to 5-6A while igniting. The UPS was rated up to 800W and 7.1A output.

I charged the UPS for nearly a month it just sat there plugged in. It started to get cold so I got the stove running and went to simulate a power outage by pulling the plug of the UPS out of the wall. The stove made some clicking and buzzing noise, and within seconds the UPS was dead. It should have lasted ~20 min, per the calculations given by the mfg.

So I plugged the ups back into the wall, and there was a flash of light. Everything was dead. The 9A fuse on the board was gone and there was a small red disc that I thought was a ceramic capacitor next to it that also was split open and charred. I called the vendor, they told me it was a '150W surge protector' but I think the term is actually a varistor, but those look like they deal in voltages, not wattage...so maybe it's 150V.

I think I can re-solider the component on the cheap, I'm a hobbyist at best with these things but something blew this up. I suspect the UPS, but I need more than
a hunch.

#### What I know

1. The stove ran fine for 2 years on straight plugged wall power.
2. The stove ran fine while the UPS was plugged into the wall.
3. The stove did not function as expected when only running on UPS.
4. When reconnected to wall power, there was an electrical malfunction. Spontaneous exothermic event.
5. The UPS still has some functionality, as it will power a floor lamp. 6-11W LED.
6. The power is run directly back to its own breaker.

The MFG does not, nor do the recommended battery solutions, specify anything about pure sine wave, however I wondered if going from pure sine/wall to modified sine/UPS was ok, but going back from modified sine/UPS to pure sine/wall caused the issue? The pure sine thing has come up on forums.

What other things can I look at for this malfunction? I'm going to be on the hook for a control board repair if I can't make the repair work.

Comment: There is no way to diagnose a problem from these symptoms. I'd bet your batteries would be suspect as you haven't listed the age of the UPS. For you to trouble shoot this you'd need to check the functionality of the board. It's less time consuming to just order a new control board if you think you fried that.

Comment: Well of course it's easier, but also $300! I have an RMA out with the UPS vendor (It's a month old max). They may or may not cover it. Really, I'm just a nerd looking for more knowledge.